# Unable to retrieve Redux Store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sharepoint, redux

I'm writing a simple redux + typescript + react + office-fabric-ui application.
**Something is wrong in my Redux environment** but I cannot find out why because the error I get back is not much use to me.

My Redux app is divided in 4 files (Actions, Reducers, States and the Store).
I will post these files below, also the error included, hope someone can tell me what is wrong in my Redux setup.

> The error occurs when passing the store to my component via props

**Store**

```
import { combineReducers, Store, ReducersMapObject, createStore } from 'redux';
import { dialogReducer, searchStringReducer, selectedItemsReducer } from './Reducers';
import { AppState } from './State';

export const reducersMapping: ReducersMapObject = {
    searchString: searchStringReducer,
    selectedItems: selectedItemsReducer,    
    dialog: dialogReducer
};

export var AppStore: Store<AppState> = createStore<AppState>(combineReducers<AppState>(reducersMapping));
```

**Actions**

```
import { Action } from 'redux';
import { IDialogAppState, IItemsAppState } from './State';

export enum ActionTypes {
    UPDATE_DIALOG,
    UPDATE_SEARCH_STRING,
    UPDATE_SELECTED_ITEMS
}

export interface AppSearchStringActions extends Action {
    type: ActionTypes;
    value: string;
}

export interface AppDialogActions extends Action {
    type: ActionTypes;
    value: IDialogAppState;
}

export interface AppSelectedItemsActions extends Action {
    type: ActionTypes;
    value: IItemsAppState;
}

export const createUpdateDialogAction: (value: IDialogAppState) => AppDialogActions = (_value) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.UPDATE_DIALOG,
    value: _value
});

export const createUpdateSearchStringAction: (value: string) => AppSearchStringActions = (_value) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.UPDATE_SEARCH_STRING,
    value: _value
});

export const createUpdateSelectedItemsAction: (value: IItemsAppState) => AppSelectedItemsActions = (_value) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.UPDATE_SELECTED_ITEMS,
    value: _value
});
```

**Reducers**

```
import { Reducer } from 'redux';
import { AppSearchStringActions, ActionTypes, AppDialogActions, AppSelectedItemsActions } from './Actions';
import { IDialogAppState, IItemsAppState, AppState } from './State';

import {
    DEFAULT_STATE_IDIALOG,
    DEFAULT_STATE_IITEMS,
    DEFAULT_SEARCH_STRING_STATE
} from './State';

export const dialogReducer: Reducer<IDialogAppState> = (state: IDialogAppState = DEFAULT_STATE_IDIALOG, action: AppDialogActions) => {
    const newDialogState: IDialogAppState = ({
        isOpen: action.value.isOpen,
        Title: action.value.Title,
        Content: action.value.Content
    });

    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.UPDATE_DIALOG:
        console.log('Reducer has updated the Dialog: ' + newDialogState);
            return newDialogState;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const searchStringReducer: Reducer<string> = (state: string = DEFAULT_SEARCH_STRING_STATE, action: AppSearchStringActions) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.UPDATE_SEARCH_STRING:
            console.log("Reducer has updated the searchString: " + action.value);
            return action.value;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const selectedItemsReducer: Reducer<IItemsAppState> = (state: IItemsAppState = DEFAULT_STATE_IITEMS, action: AppSelectedItemsActions) => {
    const newState: IItemsAppState = {
        selectedItemName: action.value.selectedItemName,
        count: action.value.count
    };

    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.UPDATE_SELECTED_ITEMS:
            console.log("Reducer has updated the items state: " + newState);
            return newState;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

**State**

```
export interface IDialogAppState {
    isOpen: boolean;
    Title: string;
    Content: string;
}
export const DEFAULT_STATE_IDIALOG: IDialogAppState = {
    isOpen: false,
    Title: "",
    Content: ""
};

export interface IItemsAppState {
    count: number;
    selectedItemName: string;
};

export const DEFAULT_STATE_IITEMS: IItemsAppState = {
    count: 0,
    selectedItemName: ""
};

export interface AppState {
    searchString: string;
    selectedItems: IItemsAppState;
    dialog: IDialogAppState;
};

export const DEFAULT_SEARCH_STRING_STATE = "";
export const DEFAULT_STATE: AppState = {
    searchString: DEFAULT_SEARCH_STRING_STATE,
    selectedItems: DEFAULT_STATE_IITEMS,
    dialog: DEFAULT_STATE_IDIALOG
};
```

**The error** (but I think this is reflecting a result of the problem, not the cause so you might ignore it).

> [SPWebPartErrorCode.ScriptLoadError]:: Unable to load web part
>   WebPart.CompContainerWebPart.ced8cf14-1b0d-4762-ae73-58e62f6783bf,Error:
>   ***Failed to load component "ef65c0df-ff5c-4535-9852-6dc48f43efb6" (CompContainerWebPart). Original error: ***Failed to load entry point
>   from component "ef65c0df-ff5c-4535-9852-6dc48f43efb6"
>   (CompContainerWebPart). script resources due to: {1}. CALLSTACK::
>   Error at SPError
>   (https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-loader/dist/sp-loader_en-us.js:13577:11)
>   at SPWebPartError
>   (https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-webpart-base/dist/sp-webpart-base_en-us.js:988:11)
>   at SPWebPartError.create
>   (https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-webpart-base/dist/sp-webpart-base_en-us.js:1012:11)
>   at Anonymous function
>   (https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-webpart-base/dist/sp-webpart-base_en-us.js:1884:23)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was located in my **Reducer**:

```
export const dialogReducer: Reducer<IDialogAppState> = (state: IDialogAppState = DEFAULT_STATE_IDIALOG, action: AppDialogActions) => {
    const newDialogState: IDialogAppState = ({
        isOpen: action.value.isOpen,
        Title: action.value.Title,
        Content: action.value.Content
    });

    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.UPDATE_DIALOG:
        console.log('Reducer has updated the Dialog: ' + newDialogState);
            return newDialogState;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

I was setting the `newDialogState` before my `switch case`.
Redux initializes all stores with a `@@Init` value what made the reducer crash.
Moving the `newDialogState` into the `switch case` solved it ;)